# eslint propvalidation suddenly way too strict

Tags: reactjs, validation, eslint, react-props

All of a sudden my eslint prop validation became way too strict and is denying me from comitting to git. It seems like it nests down in objects that already is set in propTypes.

Example:

This is the one I have in static PropTypes `agreements: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired` and this is what it complains about `194:37  error  'agreements.fetching' is missing in props validation`. I dont want a check on agreements.fetching and neither did it used to be like that. Is there a way I can set it to only the object itself?

Comment: Why are you using `PropTypes.shape({})` instead of `PropTypes.object` then?

Comment: @Sulthan cause shape is used for objects in proptypes when the key is different type, which it often is in my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the solution for my problem was to remove {} inside `PropTypes.shape().isRequired` . Seems like if you have the object parentheses you need to require what type the key are as well. If you just want the PropType to be object and dont want to validate the nested keys, then just use `shape()` and not `shape({})`